# How to Implement Generic Method to do Math calculations on different value types

Tags: c#, generics

I have a method that accepts an IEnumerable-decimals and performance various math functions. I want to use the same method on an IEnumerable-int-.  How do I implement this? For example to find a simple sum?

```
void Calculate<T>(IEnumerable <T> ListOFNumbers)
{
   int count= ListofNumbers.Count();
   ?sum=?;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is all freely available in [MiscUtil](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/). The `Operator` class provides access to generic arithmetic; and there are generic implementations (as extension methods) of `Sum`, `Average`, etc - and works with **any** type with suitable operators in addition to the primitives. So for example, you could use Sum with of [`Complex<T>`](http://csharpindepth.com/ViewNote.aspx?NoteID=50), etc.

Note that it currently uses .NET 3.5; I did have a 2.0 version somewhere, but it isn't as tested....

A **simplified** example of sum is shown in the [usage document](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/usage/genericoperators.html):

```
public static T Sum<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    T sum = Operator<T>.Zero;
    foreach (T value in source)
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            sum = Operator.Add(sum, value);
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Although IIRC the *actual* implementation has a bit more...

As an aside, note that `dynamic` (in .NET 4.0 / C# 4.0) supposedly supports operators, but we'll have to wait for the beta to see what it does. From my previous looks at `dynamic` in the CTP, I *expect* it to be a bit slower than the MiscUtil code, but we shall see.

Comment: how much slower would this be than non-generic?

Comment: I don't have metrics to hand - but it wasn't much slower at all. The `foreach` is still by far the dominant factor.

Comment: How the generic arithmetics offered by MiscUtil works internally?

Comment: It uses Expression (.NET 3.5) to build the operators, compiles them to delegates, and caches them. I did have a 2.0 version kicking around somewhere. A *simplified* example of how it is implemented is shown here: http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/genericoperators.html

Comment: I've asked because we have similar framework: http://help.dataobjects.net/##DataObjects.Net_4-Essentials.chm/html/N_Xtensive_Core_Arithmetic.htm

Comment: It's implemented differently (it uses our AssociateProvider to get some associate logic related to the particular  type), but the result must be the same from the point of performance of a single operation.

Comment: Does anyone know if the `MiscUtil` project is still around somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [IEnumerable.Sum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534734.aspx) function

Answer (score 0):

This is purely looking and jumping around in reflector.

```
{
   IQueryable qt = ListofNumbers.AsQueryable();
   Console.WriteLine(qt.Sum());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in LINQ Aggregate(...) method to do this and many other more complicated calculations i.e.

```
int[] n = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6 };
int sum = n.Aggregate((x, y) => x + y);
```

as the lamdba is executed, once for each element in the enumeration the values of x,y are

```
0,1
1,2
3,3
6,4,
10,4,
14,5,
19,5
24,6
```

respectively and the final result is 30

With this you can use any aggregating function you want:

For example:

```
int[] n = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6 };
int count = n.Aggregate((x, y) => x + 1);
```

To simplify this there are built-in functions for common aggregates like Count and Max.
Hope this helps

Alex

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work with generics?
The Aggregate method is a generic, and the action you pass in can do anything you want, so if can work with any type, so yeah t + t won't work for every T but you can do anything in the action so why does that matter?

Comment: The question starts with "IEnumerable <T> ListOFNumbers". Given that *and just that*, try to use Aggregate to do a sum. You can't, because operators (+ etc) aren't supported for C# generics. At all.

Comment: Okay I see where you are coming from. I was just asserting that if you needed special operators you could implement them in the lambda you pass to the aggregate method.